# NUMBER OF DIFFERENT RESULTANT STRINGS question on leetcode

Tags: c

**Question:**
International Morse Code defines a standard encoding where each letter is mapped to a series of dots and dashes, as follows: "a" maps to ".-", "b" maps to "-...", "c" maps to "-.-.", and so on.

```
For convenience, the full table for the 26 letters of the English alphabet is given below:
[".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."]
```

Now, given a list of words, each word can be written as a concatenation of the Morse code of each letter. For example, "cab" can be written as "-.-..--...", (which is the concatenation "-.-." + ".-" + "-..."). We'll call such a concatenation, the transformation of a word.

**Return the number of different transformations among all words we have.**
For example:

```
**Example:**
Input: words = ["gin", "zen", "gig", "msg"]
Output: 2
**Explanation:**
The transformation of each word is:
"gin" -> "--...-."
"zen" -> "--...-."
"gig" -> "--...--."
"msg" -> "--...--."
There are 2 different transformations, "--...-." and "--...--.".
```

**Answer I did:**
**I am getting wrong for the input when I submitted my code of the above example
I am getting output as 4.
But when I debug by taking the above one in onlinegdb.com , I am getting correct output i.e 2**

```
    #include<string.h>

    int uniqueMorseRepresentations(char ** words, int wordsSize){
    int i=0,j,count=wordsSize;
    for(;i<wordsSize-1;i++)
    {
        if(words[i]!=NULL)
        {
             for(j=i+1;j<wordsSize;j++)
        {
            if(words[j]!=NULL)
            {
               if(strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0)
               {
                   count--;
               }
            }
        }
            words[i]=NULL;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Note that you cannot possibly solve this problem without consulting the Morse Code strings.  Looking at the letters alone will miss the two matches in the sample input.  The most simple-minded solution is to (1) store the fully expanded morse code sequence for each input string, then (2) look for duplicates among the fully expanded more code sequences.  You will need some scratch strings for this.

Comment: If I use strcmp() there why it would not work? Thank you very much!  Could you please explain?

Comment: Look at the two words "gin" and "zen".  They expand to the same Morse Code sequence, right?  Now, how could you possibly determine that without looking at the codes for each letter?  You *have* to know the code for each letter, and you have to use that information.  Without it, there's no way to know that "gin" and "zen" are the same, right?  All the posted code is doing is looking for common substrings at the end of "gin" and "zen".  Sure, it might find "n" at the end, but how will it know that "gi" and "ze" are the same?

Comment: If this problem could be solved by only looking at the input strings, and ignoring the Morse Code table, then it really wouldn't be a Morse Code problem at all, would it?  The More Code table isn't there to confuse you.  It's there because the problem can't be solved without it, as you're discovering.

Comment: Now I understood it. Thank you very much

Comment: One thing this problem demonstrates is that Morse Code is inherently ambiguous.  Unless you know where the letter boundaries are, there's a chance that you could group the dots and dashes incorrectly, ending up with "gin" in place of "zen" or vice versa.

Comment: Please also think of this problem as a set of separate problems chained together. As an exercise, you could make a program that takes lines of input and simply outputs lines of morse. Then you could for example do `./morse <input.txt | sort -c` and that would give only unique outputs. Adding `| wc -l` would simply count those lines. This could inspire you to separate logic in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to consider the timings as well. A simple C# example can be found  at https://github.com/zizwiz/Convert-Text-to-Morse-and-Play-it There is a readme.pdf that explains some deeper detail.

It uses the timings as follows

```
<summary>
Dot = 1 unit
Dash = 3 units

Between dots and dashes in letter = 1 unit
Between Chars = 3 units
Between words = 7 units
</summary>
```